# How can I develop this graphic?

Tags: html, css, web, graph

I need some advice from you on how to develop a website with this menu. Tips? I tried with div and img, but it's too messed up.

Thank you in advance

[Web site from the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zx1n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on the CSS manipulations with shadows : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

You can also build more advanced structures like this 3D boxes: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/27/3d-shading-with-box-shadows/